# Android SQLite select IS NOT NULL

Tags: android, sqlite, null

I'm trying to retrieve only the data that are `not NULL` in a database table, but the `IS NOT NULL` clause does not seem to work. The null fields are also displayed.

```
String sql = "SELECT _id, nome_sotto FROM Categorie
 WHERE nome_categoria = '"+i.getStringExtra("categoria")+"' 
AND nome_sotto IS NOT NULL ORDER BY nome_sotto  ASC";
```

---

```
private void list() {
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
final List<Dettaglio> dettagli = new ArrayList<Dettaglio>();

String sql = "SELECT _id, nome_sotto FROM Categorie
 WHERE nome_categoria = '"+i.getStringExtra("categoria")+"' 
AND nome_sotto IS NOT NULL ORDER BY nome_sotto  ASC";

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        Dettaglio d = new Dettaglio();

        d.id = c.getString(0);
        d.sottocat = c.getString(1);                                

        dettagli.add(d);
    }
    c.close();


db.close();

ListAdapter adapter....
}
```

Comment: share output pls , what you are getting in response

Comment: being an empty field the output is the empty row of the ListView.

Comment: Add some logging to capture the result of the query, and then add it to your question. Also show us the code where you issue the query and process the results.

Comment: possibly the value is a string containing `null`.

Comment: Are you sure the `_id` field is a String? It's normally a `long` for database queries, and CursorAdapter expects it to be a `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty is not the same as null. If you want to filter out empty values AND null values, you would need to add: `AND nome_sotto != ''`